# how to convert my view table into excel format

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in ruby on rails, I want to export my view table in excel format, I have tried so many times but I can not able to export view table. **I have a view (Employee_Information) in my database and all data displaying into view.html.erb page, there is no specific model for Employee_Information view.** I have follow this tutorial "http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel", but I this tutorial export data into excel from view table with the help of model, I want to with out model.

```
**excel_file.html.erb**
`<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Employee ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Date of birth</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Marital status</th>
    <th>Father Name</th>
    <th>Spouse Name</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Employee Address</th>
    <th>Account Number</th>
    <th>IFSC Code</th>
    <th>PAN Number</th>
    <th>Client Name</th>
    <th>Designation</th>
    <th>Employee Type</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Joining date</th>
    <th>End date</th>
    <th>Offer CTC</th>
    <th>Client Address</th>    
  </tr>
  <% @employees.each do |emp| %>   
    <tr>
       <th><%= emp['employee_id'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['full_name'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['gender'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['dob_date'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['email'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['married_status'] %></th>
        <th> <%= emp['father_name'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['spouse_name'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['contact_phone'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['candidate_address2'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['bank_ac'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['bank_ifsc'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['pan_number'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['company_name'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['designation'] %></th>
        <th>
            <% if emp['employee_type'] == 0 %>
                Internal Employee
            <% elsif emp['employee_type'] == 1 || emp['employee_type'] == 2 || emp['employee_type'] == 3 %>
                Contract Consultant Employee
            <% elsif emp['employee_type'] == 4 %>
                Permanent Consultant Employee
            <% elseif emp['employee_type'] == 5 %>
                Past Employee
            <% end %> 
        </th>
        <th>
            <% if emp['status'] == 0 %>
                Pending
            <% elsif emp['status'] == 1 %>
                Approved
            <% elsif emp['status'] == 2 %>
                Cancelled
            <% elsif emp['status'] == 3 %>
                Accepted
            <% elsif emp['status'] == 4 %>
                Rejected
            <% elsif emp['status'] == 5 %>
                Onboarded
            <% elsif emp['status'] == 6 %>
                Offboarded
            <% end %> 
        </th>
        <th><%= emp['joining_date'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['work_end_date'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['ctc'] %></th>
        <th><%= emp['client_address2']%></th>  
    </tr>
  <% end %>  
</table>
<br><br>`

**hr_controller.rb**`def excel_file
        @employees = MysqlConnection.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM         Employee_Information where employee_type IN(0)")
        #@employees = MysqlConnection.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM Employee_Information where employee_type IN(1,2,3)")
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.csv { send_data @employees.to_csv }
        end
    end`
**application.rb**



  require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
     # add HR role
     require "csv"
```

I have created a file module "employee_information.rb" into lib folder

```
  module EmployeeInformation    
      def self.to_csv(options = {})
        CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
            csv << column_names
            all.each do |product|
              csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
            end
        end
    end end
```

Comment: why do you want to use a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this have to be a view table? Unless you make this some kind of form there is no way to do this without using javascript to parse the DOM (or rather access all the elements in the DOM) and get the value and make a request to a controller with the information from the parsed DOM. If you could make this some kind of submit form it would be much easier for you to export this information to excel. Either way there really is not another way to do this with out a model of some  sort.